# Is it normal that TypeTag object takes more than a second to initialize?

Tags: performance, scala, reflection, scala-2.11

`TypeTag` when first referenced in code takes more than a second on my computer to be loaded and initialized.

The time can be measured by invoking the following code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

object Boot extends App {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  TypeTag
  println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)
}
```

Is it normal? 
If yes, what is the best way to initialize this object, should I reference it in some startup initialization code of my application? I've already experienced some vague timeouts because of this object being referenced for the first time in the application inner code.

I'm using scala 2.11.7.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging shows what is taking this long is:

```
new runtime.JavaUniverse
```

In

```
package object runtime {
  // ...
  lazy val universe: api.JavaUniverse = new runtime.JavaUniverse
```

I have also tested normal TypeTag usage also shows the same behaviour.

As it is caused by an initialization of a lazy val, referencing it in startup seems like a sound way to avoid pausing at first use.

Comment: 2.12 seems a bit slower.